# I am trying to print each alphabet beside eachother in a for loop in python. Please help me

Tags: python, security, passwords

Ok so I am making a password maker in python and I am trying to create a secure password that shows up in the console like this:

**Fdm6:yguiI**

I also want the user to specify the number of alphabets the password will need (which actually works)

anyway, here is the code

```
import random

options = '1234567890!@#$%^&*()`~-_=+\|]}[{\'";:/?.>,<QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
char_list = tuple(options)

print("""Password checker
This either checks your password or creates a sequre password.
Your commands are \"create password\" and \"check password\"""")

command = str(input('Type your command: '))

if command.lower() == 'create password':
    digit_count = int(input('How many digits do you want your password to be? (Must be more than five and under 35): '))

    if digit_count >= 5 and digit_count <= 35:
        for i in range(digit_count):
            password = random.choice(char_list)
            print(password)

    else:
        print('Bruh I told you to give more than 5 or under 35')
```

Right now, the output is like this
[image]

Someone please help mee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `end` parameter to your output print statement -

```
  for i in range(digit_count):
        password = random.choice(char_list)
        print(password,end='')
```

By default, the `end` is equal to '\n'. So it changes the line if you do not specify the end as '' (empty)

If you do want to store the password, then use a list comprehension -

```
p = [random.choice(char_list) for i in range(digit_count)]
password = ''.join(p) # Or, you could just write this into a single line
print(password)
```

Comment: You're not really saving the final password in the `password` variable though :)

Comment: That is up to the him if he wants to store it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part

```
for i in range(digit_count):
    password = random.choice(char_list)
    print(password)
```

with:

```
password = ''.join(random.choices(char_list, k=digit_count))
print(password)
```